# Apply scope to association on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've a `products` table and `product_variants`, which has a `has_many` relationship with `products`

I want to retrieve all available products and its available variants.

The `Product` model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  scope :only_enabled,   -> { where(status: :enabled) }
  scope :only_in_stock,  -> { where('quantity > 0') }
  scope :only_available, -> { only_enabled.only_in_stock }
end
```

and the `ProductVariant` model:

```
class ProductVariant < ApplicationRecord
  scope :only_enabled,   -> { where(status: :enabled) }
  scope :only_in_stock,  -> { where('inventory_quantity > 0') }
  scope :only_available, -> { only_enabled.only_in_stock }
end
```

How can I retrieve all `Product.only_available` with its `ProductVariant.only_available`, not excluding the products if the variants don't match the `ProductVariant.only_available` scope?

I've tried to use this query:

```
@store.products.only_available.joins(:category).joins('LEFT JOIN product_variants ON product_variants.product_id = products.id AND product_variants.status = 1 AND product_variants.inventory_quantity > 0')
Product Load (4.4ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "products"."category_id" LEFT JOIN product_variants ON product_variants.product_id = products.id AND product_variants.status = 1 WHERE "products"."store_id" = $1 AND "products"."status" = $2 AND (quantity > 0) ORDER BY "products"."name" ASC  [["store_id", "129031"], ["status", 1]]
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to be filtering the unavailable variants.

Comment: How about this `Product.only_available.left_outer_joins(:product_variants).merge( ProductVariant .only_available )`?

Comment: `.joins` uses `INNER JOIN` that would exclude products without variants

Comment: Please have a look my edited comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `where` to filter the association.

```
@store.products.only_available
  .eager_load(:product_variants)
  .where('product_variants IS NULL OR (product_variants.status = 1 AND product_variants.inventory_quantity > 0)')
```

I had to do this `association IS NULL OR ( ... )` to make it work the way I was expecting.